Finding the effect of a change of medium on a general EM wave
For plane waves changing medium we can use the fresnel equations, is there a more general method for other waves? (spherical, parabolic etc)
I thought maybe treating this as a diffraction problem and solving with fourier optics but this requires various approximations and I'm wondering if there is a better way.
